# how to clear history of WebBrowser control c#/.net

Tags: webbrowser-control, browser-history, clear-cache

How to clear WebBrowser control history in c# Windows Form

Answer (score 0):

this project will show how to clear history browser
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7500/The-Tiny-Wrapper-Class-for-URL-History-Interface-i